# Cakephp - how to add strikethrough to output

Tags: html, css, cakephp-3.0

I have the output `<td><?= h($book->price) ?></td>` now i'd like to add a strikethrough tag to the output if `$book->sales_price` is not null. How would I add the code for strikethrough?

```
if($book->sales_price){
//add strikethrough
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the strike through tag `<s> Sample Text </s>` or `<strike> Sample Text </strike>`

<strike>Sample Text</strike>

```
if(is_null($book->sales_price)) {
  <td><?= h($book->price) ?></td>
} else {
  <td><s><?= h($book->price) ?></s></td>
}
```